# GET parameter when rewritten by htaccess

Tags: php, url, variables, dynamic

This is my default dynamic link:

> www.example.com/news/index.php?id=5&title=Test-Title-3

This is the link that have been rewritten by htaccess:

> www.example.com/news/5/Test-Title-3

Now I wish to get the id variable (which is 5) and/or title variable (which is Test-Title-3) with PHP.

I have tried using `$_GET['id']` but returns

> index.php/Test-Title-3

or using $_GET['title'] which returns nothing. Any idea how to get the variable?

(Edited)
This is my .htaccess file, in case of need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks Options All -Indexes 
<files .htaccess> 
  order allow,deny 
  deny from all 
</files>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/ index.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

Comment: you need to add [QSA] flag at the end RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/ index.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA]

Comment: hey thanks! it works, I feel really stupid just missing that flag

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess rewrite rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]+)$ /news/index.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

`$1` and `$2` are defined based on the expression contained within `(` and `)`.
This will show the url `www.example.com/news/5/Test-Title-3` to the user while your script's actual URL will be `www.example.com/news/index.php?id=5&title=Test-Title-3` so you will be able to use `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['title']` as you normally would.

Comment: I did try to use your rule, but suddenly it returns error 404. Maybe I should change my link href too?

Comment: No need, there was a bug in the regular expression. It works now (tested with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ )

Answer (score 0):

you can get the id value using php. Just use the following code:

```
   <?php
      $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      $val = explode("/", $url);
      echo "Your id is: ".$val[2];
   ?>
```

Hope this helps!!!